# Not able to refer the dropdown menu value in the class

Tags: ios, swift, drop-down-menu

I using below code for dropdown menu, which working fine.
only thing I am not able to do is that when the dropdown menu value changed in the extension I am not able to call it in the class. I am learning swift, please help. I am using this open source code https://github.com/teambition/DropdownMenu

All I want is the value chosen in the dropdown menu could used and processed in the class

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var sectionSwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var offSetSlider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var offsetLabel: UILabel!

    var showSection: Bool = true
    var selectedRow: Int = 0
    var selectedIndexPath: IndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    var items: [[DropdownItem]]!
    var selecteditem: String!
    var selecteditem2: String!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

           }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func showMenu(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let item1 = DropdownItem(title: "NO Image")
        let item2 = DropdownItem(title: "File")
        let item3 = DropdownItem(title: "Post", style: .highlight)
        let item4 = DropdownItem(title: "Event", style: .highlight, accessoryImage: UIImage(named: "accessory")!)

        var menuView: DropdownMenu?
            items = [[item1, item2, item3, item4]]
            menuView = DropdownMenu(navigationController: navigationController!, items: [item1, item2, item3, item4], selectedRow: selectedRow)

        menuView?.zeroInsetSeperatorIndexPaths = [IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)]
        menuView?.delegate = self
        menuView?.rowHeight = 50
        menuView?.showMenu()
    }

}


extension ViewController: DropdownMenuDelegate {
    func dropdownMenu(_ dropdownMenu: DropdownMenu, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedIndexPath = indexPath
        selecteditem = (items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].title)
        selecteditem2 = selecteditem
      //  print("DropdownMenu didselect \(indexPath.row) text:\(items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].title)")
       if indexPath.row != items.count - 1 {
            self.selectedRow = indexPath.row
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: you're getting the selected value in the didSelect function in the extension. What exactly are you unable to do?

Comment: @ThePedestrian I want the value selected in the extension to be called in the class so that I can use that value for another type of function

Comment: the way I see it, you're getting the value in selecteditem & selecteditem2 properties.You can use the same in your class.

Comment: @ThePedestrian I am not able to do so, can you please show me some code for that?

Comment: Buddy are you expecting some change in the UI? uncomment the print statement below selectedItem2 and check whether you're getting a value in there?

Comment: @ThePedestrian yes I am getting value there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204124/discussion-between-the-pedestrian-and-ramneek-kashyap).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var selecteditem2: String!{
didSet{
//update your UI here. write the code for updation here.
}
}
```

if you need the value that you have just inserted.:

```
var selecteditem2: String!{
willSet{
/*update your UI here. write the code for updation here.
the new value is :newValue 
newValue is the default argument name here. You can use it as it is.
*/  
}
}
```

Comment: Glad to be of help bro :)